# Django - Creating a sub ID based on a unique_together constraint for a subset of a table

Tags: python, django

I have a conceptual problem I dont know how to handle. I want to give a new id (starting at 0) to a subset of a table based on a unique_together constaint

To conceptualize my problem, lets take a Books and Chapters model

```
class Books(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)


class Chapters(modes.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Books)
    chapter_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)

    def Meta(self):
        unique_together = (("book", "chapter_id"),)
```

In resume, I want to give to every chapters of a book a chapter_id from 0 to n

Is there a way to do that in django? Actually, I was doing something like below to increment the chapter_id in the save method of the Chapters model. The problem is sometimes chapters are saved simultaneously and the same chapter_id is given to many chapters and the unique_together constraint prevent it to be saved.

```
def cal_chapter_id(book):
    chapters = Feature.objects.filter(book=book).aggregate(Max('chapter_id'))
    if chapters['chapter_id__max'] is not None:
        return chapters['chapter_id__max'] + 1
    else:
        return 0

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.chapter_id is None:
        self.chapter_id  = cal_chapter_id(self.book)
    super(Chapters, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229997/github-issue-ids-start-at-1-for-each-repository-how-can-i-replicate-this-in-dja/26230165#26230165

Comment: yes I could give a try to that. Thank you. However, I suppose I have to remove the unique_together constraint with that solution?

Comment: the generating method would never allow for a duplicate, but you can create a constraint anyway if you intend to add records manually

Comment: If you don't require a special order in your chapters you could try to run try: super().save() break; except IntegrityError: icrement id in a loop